# Java:Reading Error

Tags: java, swing, io, jtextarea

I got problem in reading the file at the Gui text area hopefully you help me out guys to fix the statement of reading file thank you very much

```
 public static javax.swing.JTextArea jTextArea1;
{
    BufferedReader br = null;

    try {

        String sCurrentLine;

        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\testing1.txt"));

        while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            jTextArea1.read(br, "C:\\testing1.txt"); \\the problem is here
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (br != null)br.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try passing a File object to JTextArea.read() in stead of a String.  You can read the documentation for JTextComponent.read() [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#read).

Comment: Do you want to put the contents read from file to the `JTextArea`?

Comment: @jahroy thank you but I would like to read it from jtextarea

Comment: Yes... and _JTextArea_ extends _JTextComponent_, so that's the method you'll be invoking ;-)  You'll be much better off if you learn to read the API documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
 JtextArea1.setText(readtext);
```

but when you use

```
 jTextArea1.append(readtext);
```

that will append data at the end of  already read text in jTextArea

Comment: It's keep give me tons of errors when i use one of them but I remove it and use System.out.Println(sCurrentLine); it works normal but gui not work with me

Comment: @Amador - I haven't touched a Swing app in over 12 years, but it sounds like you might be doing things in the wrong thread.  I say this because I've read dozens of questions on this site where people try to do _GUI stuff_ outside of the thread where _GUI stuff_ should be done.  Try googling "_swing event dispatch thread_" for more info...

Comment: @jahroy exactly I do this I do gui and modify it :D so I try do it easier

Comment: I copied with modify the answeres my code in Eclipse and it worked .. I dunno the reason but finally it did :)) thanx alot all :)

Comment: @Sikander I used set but the problem with in threads coz I used ready GUI so Changed the netbeans to Eclipse and made jframe and text area and it worked with set and read the file .. thank you Sikander and thank you all for answers :)

Answer (score 0):

Try one of the following:

```
jTextArea1.read(br, null);
```

or

```
jTextArea1.append(sCurrentLine);
```

Have a look at this link: http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/GUI/components/40textarea/20textarea.html

Comment: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at javaapplication9.Project2.<init>(Project2.java:123)
 at javaapplication9.Project2$1.run(Project2.java:103)
 at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)

it gave me all these errors when i remove it it back normal